# Is a compromised SQL Server sa account without a domain login enough to access database?

Tags: authentication, sql-server

If a SQL Server account with system administrator rights is compromised but there is no access to a domain account, port 1433 is not exposed outside of the corporate firewall and SQL injection is not possible, is a compromise of the SQL Server database possible?

Comment: Port 1433 is not exposed to where? How do you connect to the database? From whom are you defending?

Comment: @MarkoVodopija - I've updated the question. 1433 is not exposed outside of the corporate firewall. The question is with respect to any attacker outside of the domain.

Comment: It's possible if the attacker has access to the network the database is on. That could be achieved with physical intrusion, a compromised workstation, misconfigured proxy, and many other routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no access to connect to the database, either directly or indirectly, then possession of the 'sa' account credentials on its own is unlikely to be beneficial for attacking the database, as the attacker can't actually make use of them.

However as @paj28 mentions in comments, attackers have a number of ways in that may not depend on an exposed port on the firewall, so if you're asking this question from the perspective of a defender, it could be dangerous to assume that the exposure of the credentials carries no risk.